# latest records in database based on created time in eloquent ORM

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

My table size is big.I use two query i think that is costly. I need efficient query.

**Sample**

```
id   qt      created_at
---  ----    -----------
1   1        2017-07-28
2   2        2017-07-28
3   3        2017-07-28
4   1        2017-07-29
5   2        2017-07-29
6   3        2017-07-20
```

And i want to display  latest

```
4   1        2017-07-29
5   2        2017-07-29
```

I do this using two query. i think it's not efficient. i want efficient query.

**my code**

```
$last_time = Table::orderBy('created_at','desc')->first()->created_at;
$latest_records = Table::where('created_at','=',$last_time)->get();
```

Comment: I think you can use like: `$record = DB::table('your_table_name')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first(); dd($record);` Try this and let me know!

Comment: it return one records, i need multiple @HirenGohel

Comment: Try with this: `$record = DB::table('your_table_name')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); dd($record);`

Comment: it return all records. i need only latest by created_at@HirenGohel

Comment: See, `->first()` gives you latest record, as you have two same record with `created_at`. `->get();` gives you all record. So first try to enter only one record at a time in created_at column which is Unix timestamp! Got it?

Comment: I have posted my answer, i think you get idea from my answer! Please see it.

Comment: it is not possible by order_by. i need slice of data not all or one. if latest is one then return one if latest is multiple the return multiple. order_by can only ordered data as asc or desc

Answer (score 0):

First, make a column `Unix Timestamp` for `created_at`!

Please read about Laravel date mutators: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

> By default, timestamps are formatted as 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. If you need to customize the timestamp format, set the $dateFormat property on your model. This property determines how date attributes are stored in the database, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an array or JSON

Also, you can override `getDateFormat()`:

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
     return 'U';
}
```

And use this in your migration files:

```
$table->integer('updated_at');
$table->integer('created_at');
```

And, if you use soft deletes:

```
$table->integer('deleted_at');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps

Then you can get record like:

```
$record = DB::table('your_table_name')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); dd($record);
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: read the question carefully. please see the discussion   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-can-i-get-the-latest-record-in-database-based-on-datetime

Comment: read question again. give my code in question body. i do this by different way and need efficient query.

Comment: I know there is no any best solution in their discussion, but have you tried any of them which they discussed?

Comment: there is not efficient solution

Comment: What this gives you?: `DB::table('your_table_name')->latest()->first();` Only one record or multiple? OR `DB::table('your_table_name')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->latest()->first();`

Comment: What is result of my above comment?

Comment: in eloquent orm latest() return orderBy($column, 'desc');(please read details of latest() line:1430 https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php) so it isn't possible by latest()

Comment: Definitely  not for latest()

Comment: Ok, have you get the solution for this currently?

Comment: I know my answer is not giving your solution as you need, but this answer is not wrong at all! So, why are you downvoted it?

Comment: are you sure you got downtown by me? if not sure why such comment like threat.